# How do I correctly setup MDBootstrap with my standard Laravel project

Tags: php, css, laravel, web-frameworks, mdbootstrap

I am in the process of learning how to use Laravel and I am interested in styling my web pages using MDBootstrap. However, I am confused about how to integrate it into my project correctly. I do not want to link it using CDN, instead I would like to install it into my project.

Can someone show me the necessary steps to achieve this in a basic Laravel project?

Answer (score 2):

Laravel comes with 2 frontend package managers: npm and yarn

**npm**

```
npm i mdbootstrap
```

**yarn**

```
yarn add mdbootstrap
```

After this your package is located in the ***node_modules*** directory.

You can [import sass](https://sass-lang.com/guide#topic-5) files and let the js be combined from packages to *vendor.js*.

You can [configure](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/mix) what gets transpiled to where using **webpack.mix.js**

Running `npm run dev` will start the transpiling.

---

If you want to install mdbootstrap pro, you should follow these steps

1. get a license and mail contact@mdbootstrap.com requesting access to their git repo (as they have not automated this)
2. [generate an access token on gitlab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html)
3. run

   ```
   npm install git+https://oauth2:[TOKEN]@git.mdbootstrap.com/mdb/[REPO].git --save
   ```

   Where **[TOKEN]** is your token from step 2 and **[REPO]** is the one you need from the choices jquery, angular, vue or react. You can find the exact urls by visiting [git.mdbootstrap.com](http://git.mdbootstrap.com) and choosing the right project. In the top right corner find the **clone** button and copy the **https** link.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use CLI /NPM there is an easy way to import MDBootstrap in to Laravel.

Simply copy the mdb.min.js and mdb.min.js.map to your public/js folder.
Next copy the mdb css files (there should be around 8 of them) to your public/css folder.

Now in the HTML blade files (I use a head blade include file for this) add the following:

```
 <!-- import MDB Pro -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/mdb.min.css" />
```

...then just before your closing BODY tag (I use a "foot" blade include), add the following:

```
 <!-- import Font Awesome -->
 <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

 <!-- import Material Icons from Google Fonts -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">

 <!-- import the MDB javascript file https://mdbootstrap.com/ -->    
 <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('js/mdb.min.js') }}"></script>
```

...just remember to update the files when new releases occur. Because it won't happen automatically without NPM.